# Interfaces with abstract classes inheritance

Tags: java

Hey guys so Im new to Java and I'm having some trouble getting the hang of Interfaces, abstract classes etc.. So here I have this problem that I'm not sure to solve. Basically I have this one Interface that is susposed to be implemented by an abstract class, and that abstract class is susposed to "have" (not sure what the right term is ) a few other classes.Now I think I did the first part:

```
abstract class AbstractArticle implements Article {
final private String name;
final private double price;
final private String description;

AbstractArticle(String name,double price,String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.description = description;     
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}



class Accessory extends AbstractArticle {
final String instructionsForUse;

Accessory(String name, double price, String description, String instructionsForUse) {
    super(name,price,description);
    this.instructionsForUse = instructionsForUse;
}

public String getinstructionsForUse() {
    return instructionsForUse;
}

class Merchandise implements Article {
final private int quantity;
Article article;

Merchandise(Article article) {
    this.article = article;
    quantity = 0;   
}

Merchandise(Article article, int quantity) {
    this.article = article;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public Article getArticle() {
    return article;
}
```

}

So firstly I needed to make an abstract class override the methods and use getters to get the values, than I needed to extend the abstract class use a super constructor to call the methods getName etc.. (hopefully I did that right) and now in the class merchandise I am susposde to have 2 constructors the first one (Article article) is susposded to set the value of quantity to 0 which doesnt make sense to me,shouldn't it be done in the second constructor?Now the problem is when I try to compile the Merchandise class i get an error saying I need to make the class abstract or override the method getDescription(). Is there any way I could avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: `Article` has a `getDescription` method you're not implementing? The way to avoid the error is to pick one of the options--if you define your class as implementing an interface that class must either (a) be implemented, or (b) be abstract, like the error says. It's not clear what specifically you're wondering about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you're trying to implement a [*Decorator Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern): `Merchandise` both *is a* `Article` and *has a* `Article`.

Your `Merchandise` class basically wraps an existing `Article` and adds a `quantity` field to it. The idea is that a `Merchandise` is an "`Article` with a quantity".

If you want to be able to treat a `Merchandise` instance as an `Article`, you need to define the methods declared in the `Article` interface. Presumably here the idea is just to have those methods return the same thing the wrapped `Article` instance returns, which you do with:

```
class Merchandise implements Article {

    final private int quantity;
    Article article;

    Merchandise(Article article) {
        this.article = article;
        quantity = 0;   
    }

    Merchandise(Article article, int quantity) {
        this.article = article;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return article.getDescription();
    }

    // and similarly for any other methods declared in Article

    // you might not really want (or need) this:
    public Article getArticle() {
        return article;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmmm okay I see but why wouldnt i want or need teh get article method? Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @arhzzz Because the `Merchandise` instance already has all the functionality of the wrapped `Article`, via the methods it exposes (such as `getDescription()`). It's essentially an implementation detail that shouldn't be exposed as public API.

Comment: Hmmm okay thank you for your help I'll try to remember that in the future